# Visual Composer not loading Hubspot form embed

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, hubspot

I'm working on a Wordpress site that was built using Visual Composer. I'm trying to embed a Hubspot form, which is something I have done numerous times but never using VC. I figured it would be as simple as adding a "raw html" block in VC and adding the form embed script.

This does indeed load the form, however it is displayed on the bottom left of the screen instead of the right column where it was set. However, if the page is refreshed, it displays as it should, no problems. This makes me think the script is loaded after the rest of the page is loaded.

I have tried creating a shortcode for the script and inserting in the VC section. Does not work.

You can see the issue here:
http://yourveininstitute.com/leg-swelling/
( form loads at the bottom of page and loads correctly on refresh )

The HS embed code looks like this ( portal and id redacted ):

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({ 
    css: '',
    portalId: '######',
    formId: '#################'
  });
</script>
```

I could really use some help on this one. I'm spinning my wheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing a hubspot form loading correctly in the sidebar, even on the first load. Are you still experiencing the problem? If so, I might try enqueueing the external script call, and only putting the hbspt.forms.create stuff in the VC block.

Try adding this to your functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_hubspot');
function add_hubspot() {
  wp_enqueue_script('hubspot', '//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js');
}
```

Comment: If you navigate to another page and back you can see what I mean. All of the internal pages also have the same form. I tried what you suggested above and unfortunately it is still happening.

Comment: Ah, ok I see the form not showing up now. This is weird.. I'm wondering if the animated page transitions in the theme have anything to do with this? I might try turning those off in your theme options. I also may try wrapping the hubspot .create call in $( document ).ready(function() { /*hubspot code here*/ });

Comment: Yasss!! It was indeed the page animation feature. Thank you very much for your help with this!!

Comment: Ha! That's awesome! Glad it was something simple. Honestly that page animation idea was a shot in the dark, but it seemed like it could possibly interfere with the onload stuff. Thanks for the accepted answer!